# Html input number to accept only natural number or with ,25 or ,5

Tags: java, php, html, design-patterns, input

i'm searching for something that makes my input field accept only natural number or numbers ending with ,25 or ,5 . 
I must use it to insert time periods, and it must take only quarter, half or natural numbers.

```
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="10">
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, i did like this: <input class='form-control input-qty rounded' type="text" pattern="^([0-9]+|,)(25|5)?$" name="qty" value=""            onkeyup="SCalc(this)" required>. i tried both number or text. Text says i not respect the pattern, prolly something's not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should do something on the php side to reject bad inputs. This should be fairly easy. It is to prevent maybe because of super old browser not supporting javascript that breaks client-side checks.

But as you also want the check to be done before submitting, you should use Javascript Form Validation. This happens at the browser to prevent the user from submitting an incorrect form. You can see a tutorial [right there](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp). A more convenient way is described below but the JS way can be used as fallback.

For newer browsers supporting HTML5 you can use the [pattern attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) on input. It uses regex to check against the value from the user. The following regex might not be the best solution but should satisfy your requirement:

```
^([0-9]+,?|,)(25|5)?$
```

Comment: i found a little compromise with type="number" min="0" step="0.25" but i don't need to insert 0.75, suggestions?

Comment: I think setting the "pattern" attribute to this regex, and setting its type to "text" should do the work. I made a mistake on the regex. I updated the answer and please try again. Also, you should use `preg_match` on php to double check it again, as some browsers might not support form checking.

Comment: This regex would match `,25`, `5,25`, `12`, etc. If you do not want it to match `,25` replace `|,` part. If you also want to match `.` replace `,` with `[.,]`. I have tested it on my browser and it is working fine.